# ASP.NET MVC & Expression XAML - How do I integrate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xaml, expression

Some Background:
ASP.net MVC is primarly a paradigm shift in the way you structure and develop ASP.NET applications.  Shifting from a "code behind" type of mentality to more of a standard MVC Ruby on Rails like mentality.   I applaud it's efforts as a simlifying tool towards unit testing ease and seperation of code (although the html inline code could be debatable).

Expression and XAML is a way to describe the presentation layer that can be simple for designers.

The question is:

**If we are to use ASP.NET MVC in developing our next website how does the design team that uses Expression and XAML supposed to create (V)iews or integrate into the development flow?**

**More specifically can Expression users still operate in an ASP.NET MVC world?**

Note that the pages in Expression's model use a code behind paradigm as well.

Comment: The sound of new frameworks and patterns crashing ...

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.codeplex.com/caliburn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a hack, but you can use XAML to render static images in ASP.NET MVC. Check out my post XAML Meets ASP.NET MVC - Serverside Image Rendering - that shows how to render XAML and WPF controls as an image in ASP.NET MVC

http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2010/07/xaml-meets-aspnet-mvc-create-databound.html

There is also the [MvcXaml project](http://mvcxaml.codeplex.com) that is a View Engine that allows for images to be dynamically generated based on a XAML view.

http://mvcxaml.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this, making several assumptions that may be wrong.

ASP.Net MVC is a **web technology** and XAML is a **desktop one**. You can use XAML inside Internet Explorer, but it's basically a hack, it works best for desktop or silverlight applications.

If you want a paradigm similar to MVC for the desktop, you should try the **M-V-VM pattern**, who is more appropriate to WPF and XAML.
With M-V-VM you can create views almost **code-behind free**.
A **great intro** to M-V-VM is [this video by Jason Dolinger](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650)

If you are **making a website** using MVC and you are trying to integrate the design team, you should let them create the HTML+CSS views of your site, while the developers create the controllers and the models.

Please comment in this answer if I have misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently banging my head on these terms. However, maybe this  [silverlight-as-a-view-in-aspnet-mvc](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/02/09/silverlight-as-a-view-in-aspnet-mvc.aspx) article will help? You've asked about XAML, and I thing this is what Silverlight uses...